# Why does the first LSTM in a Keras model have more params than the subsequent one?

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I was just looking at the Keras model details from a fairly straightforward sequential model where I have multiple LSTM layers, one after another. I was surprised to see that the first layer always has more params despite having the same definition as the subsequent LSTM layer.

The model definition here shows it clearly:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 400, 5)            380       
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 400, 5)            220       
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_1 (TimeDist (None, 400, 650)          3900      
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (None, 400, 20)           53680     
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_4 (LSTM)                (None, 400, 20)           3280      
_________________________________________________________________
```

Similarly after a time distributed dense layer, the same is true of the next two identical LSTMs.

Is my understanding of LSTMs incorrect, that an identical definition doesn't result in the same layer being produced as a 'duplicate' tagged on the end, or is there something else in the param count that I need to understand? Currently it just looks weird to me!

Any explanation would be great to help me (a) understand better, and (b) build more performant models based on this new knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of the LSTM depends only on its `units`.

We see that your first layers have both 5 units.
And the other two have 20 units.

But the **trainable parameters** (numbers to perform calculations on the inputs and bring the expected output), those need to take into account how many input features are coming, since they will have to consider all inputs in their calculations.

The bigger the input, the more parameters are necessary. We can tell that you have more than 5 features in the input. And for the two last layers, the input of the first one is 650, against 20 of the other.

---

#### Detailed amount of parameters.

In the LSTM layer, as you can see in [their code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py/#L1602), there are 3 groups of weights:

- kernel - shaped as `(units, 4*inputs)`
- recurrent kernel - shaped as `(units,4*units)`
- bias - shaped as `(4*units,)`

With some calculations, we can infer that your inputs have shape `(None, 400, 13)`

```
Layer (type)         Output Shape        Param #   
========================================================================
input_6 (InputLayer) (None, 400, 13)     0         
________________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)        (None, 400, 5)      380   = 4*(13*5 + 5*5 + 5)   
________________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)        (None, 400, 5)      220   = 4*(5*5 + 5*5 + 5)     
________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_1   (None, 400, 650)    3900  = ?  
________________________________________________________________________
lstm_3 (LSTM)        (None, 400, 20)     53680 = 4*(650*20 + 20*20 + 20)   
________________________________________________________________________
lstm_4 (LSTM)        (None, 400, 20)     3280  = 4*(20*20 + 20*20 + 20)    
________________________________________________________________________
```

- LSTM 1 parameters = 4*(13*5 + 5*5 + 5)
- LSTM 2 parameters = 4*(5*5 + 5*5 + 5)
- Time distributed = ??
- LSTM 3 parameters = 4*(650*20 + 20*20 + 20)
- LSTM 4 parameters = 4*(20*20 + 20*20 + 20)

---

#### Other layers have similar behavior

If you test with a dense layer, you will also see that:

```
Layer (type)         Output Shape    Param #   
=========================================================
input_6 (InputLayer) (None, 13)      0      
_________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)      (None, 5)       70    = 13*5 + 5      
_________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)      (None, 5)       30    = 5*5 + 5   
_________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)      (None, 650)     3900  = 5*650 + 650     
_________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)      (None, 20)      13020 = 650*20 + 20   
_________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)      (None, 20)      420   = 20*20 + 20    
=========================================================
```

The difference is that the dense layers don't have a recurrent kernel, and their kernels are not multiplied by 4.

- Dense 1 parameters = 13*5 + 5
- Dense 2 parameters = 5*5 + 5
- Dense 3 parameters = 5*650 + 650
- Dense 4 parameters = 650*20 + 20
- Dense 5 parameters = 20*20 + 20

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I understand to a point, but I am still missing something. In my example, according to your calculations lstm_2 gets 4*(5*5 + 5*5 + 5) params. So compared to lstm_1, does this mean that the effective input width (13 input values per timestep) have been dropped and lstm_2 has been shrunk to a width of 1 rather than 13?

Comment: The width follows the number of units in each layer. LSTM1 transforms the width 13 into 5. And LSTM 2 only sees 5 coming in. Since it has 5 units, it keeps from 5 to 5, but not necessarily parallel, things get mixed up inside.

Comment: OK - that makes sense. I was missing that. So one more question to help me fully implant this in my brain... In the LSTM layer, is there a way of setting the number of timesteps over which the memory operates? How far back in time do learned state affect the current timestep? Or is that just a feature of the way the different gates interoperate, that there is no real control over this? Wow, big gap in my understanding!

Comment: As far as I know, there is no control over that. (But often people surprise me around here :) ). What people usually do to forge that memory length is to make a "sliding window" case. They divide their original sequence in smaller sequences, all little sequences have the desired length, and they overlap. Imagine you had a sequence with 5 steps, but your desired memory is 3 steps. You create three sequences: [step1, step2, step3], [step2, step3, step4], [step3, step4, step5]. And you also adjust the outputs to match this.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense now. Thanks!