# Rough estimate of number of parameters and LSTM architecture

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, lstm

The problem that I am working is a binary classification. I have around 150 sequences, where each sequence has 130000 timesteps, where each timestep has 2 features, shape=(1,130000,2). Each of these sequences is labelled as "1" or "0". I want to train an lstm network, where at the end, giving it a sequence of 130000 timesteps with 2 features each, will predict "1" or "0". Hence the problem as I have it in my mind is "many to one" right?

1) If I keep for training 120 of these sequences and the rest 30 for validation, the number of parameters of the model, should be roughly smth like 120x130000x2=31,200,000 parameters?
For example an LSTM layer with ~4000 units?

2) The network should be stateful? or not

The model as I am thinking it is smth like:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=4000,batch_input_shape=(1, 130000,2),return_sequences=False,stateful=True, 
kernel_initializer='RandomNormal'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train,validation_data=(X_test, Y_test),shuffle=False, epochs=5, batch_size=1, verbose=1)
```

Any recommendations for the approach? Am I thinking it in the correct way?

In addition, this LSTM could be trained in parallel in 4 gpus using `multi_gpu_model()` from Keras?

Should I have more samples and less timesteps for each sample?

Answer (score -1):

**Parameters:**

Parameters (as Keras calls the "model's weights") don't depend on the sequence length or the number of sequences. They depend only on the input "features" (=2) and the number of units.

Your first layer (taking 2 features as input, containing 4000 cells will have:

- 4 * (inputFeatures * units + units² + units) = 16.012.000 --- [See details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46584171/why-does-the-first-lstm-in-a-keras-model-have-more-params-than-the-subsequent-on/46586074#46586074)
- Hint: 4000 units is often overwhelmingly too much.

Your dense layer (4000 input features and 1 unit) will have:

- inputFeatures * units + units = 4001

**Stateful?**

If your task will be only the task you described (classify whole sequences) and you don't have any memory problem in processing an entire sequence at once in the model, then you have **no need to use `stateful=True`**. This would only add unnecessary complexity to your code.

So you can use `input_shape=(130000,2)` instead of `batch_input_shape`.

And your training data can be in a single array with shape (150,130000,2). Or, if you divide training and test data, two arrays: (120,130000,2) and (30,130000,2).

**GPUs**

Unfortunately I don't have that answer. But I know that LSTM's are terribly slow on GPUs. You may want to explore the CuDNNLSTM layer.

Comment: How can I decide how many units I need for this amount of data that I have? How could I start? Any preliminary calculations? For example to start the LSTM with 100 units? or will underfit?

Comment: There is no right answer for that, and it will depend on how complex your sequences are to learn. But 100 is indeed a nice start.

Comment: Should I have more samples and less timesteps for each sample? Should I transform the dataset in another way?

Comment: Are they really 150 different sequences? Do you want exactly 150 classifications? If they're 150 sequences, everything is correct.

Comment: I am treating them as different. Thats the thing that makes me not to be sure. I had seven big sequences with million timesteps each and I chopped them to segments each one. Resulting in the shape that I mention. Each one of the chopped is assigned the class of the sequence that came.

Comment: That's more complex... You could try to work with the 7 entire sequences, like in `input_shape=(None,2)`. -- But then you'd have too few samples and your model would probably just overfit very quickly.

Comment: Your approach may work very well as a form of data augmentation if: you can assure that in every segment there is enough to classify the data correctly. (Example: you have 10 seconds of audio and you want to tell if there is human voice in the audio. If you know that the voice never gets silent for more than 1 second, you could divide the audio in segments greater than 1 second and the model would detect voice. But if there is a long silence, then the model would think there is no voice in certain segments)

Comment: So you are proposing that I chop/divide each one of the 7 sequences in a way that each segment has meaningful information. Right?

Comment: That would be a possibility... but also, there is not "right answer" to this question, it depends a lot on what type of data it is, if the classification can only be done with the entire sequence or if the sequences carry the information all along, etc.